# Handling of 'ä','ö','ü' in input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, encoding

Hy,
I don't really understand why my code isn't working.
Short description:
I have implemented an auto suggest function on my own, like jquery-ui autosuggest. Unfortunately I can't use jQuery UI and I had to stick with jQuery 1.3.1 due to system restrictions.

If the user enters letters like 'ä','ö','ü' and I try to check if those letters were inserted like so:

```
if(inputFieldText.indexOf('ä')!=-1){
    alert("detection");
}
```

the page where I deployed this does not `alert()` but if I run this in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nyDBB/4/ it works fine. Everything is placed within the Document ready block and other functionalities like .click(),.change() do work fine.

I have also tried to use the `encode()` methods but that's not really a good way to work around and also gives me certain errors.

So my suggestion is that there is something wrong with setting the encoding on the page, but does anybody know how to get over this problem ?

Comment: Your fiddle didn't work for me because the selected version of jQuery doesn't have an `.on()` method (it worked when I changed it to `.bind()`: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/nyDBB/3/

Comment: yeah I'set it wrong maybe sorry I will correct it but that's not the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure everything is in UTF-8 (or any other encoding in fact).

That means **both .js and .htm** file has to have **same charset.**

For debug, you can try putting JS code into html document into `<script>` tag. Then it should work, since encoding is garanteed the same.

Comment: how do I set the encoding for .js and html files ?

Comment: Depends what editor do you use. Google "name of your editor" + set encoding/charset. Like i use Geany, then would I google "Geany set encoding".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all your source files are in UTF-8 (especially .js files). That means opening them with notepad++ and checking that the encoding of the source files is UTF-8 (sometimes eclipse doesn't use that and this causes a lot of problems).

Answer (score -2):

Use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as `.on` was added in 1.7. If your restrictions change you may want to use .delegate(), take a look at the .live reference to see when it is best to use each of them.

```
$('input').live("input change", function(e) {
    var text = e.target.value;
    console.log(text)

    if(text.indexOf('ä') != -1)
        alert("detection");
});​
```

As a side note, your jsfiddle was set to use jQuery 1.2.6, not 1.3.1 as you mentioned.

Comment: Down-vote reasoning would be hugely beneficial as I'll be able to understand what is wrong with the answer.